# How do I Google the whole trilogy of StackOverflow sites?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, google

Is it possible to Google the whole trilogy of StackOverflow sites at once?

Google only gives me two hits from a domain before asking me to search in that domain only. So if I want to search both StackOverflow and SuperUser, I'd have to look at the hits for the former, and then the hits for the latter, rather than both at once.

Comment: "Trilogy" of sites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Google custom search engine http://www.google.com/coop/cse?cx=002055035322507804868:yua2pba7w5g

Comment: Don't forget to include meta in your search too. There is valuable data in there too.

Answer (score 6):

Set up a [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/coop/cse/) for the sites you are interested in

Answer (score 4):

implemented at http://stackexchange.com (though it searches *all* sites in the network)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like something that should be built into http://www.askjonskeet.com

Comment: I was wanting to know about background processes in Unix, and the quote at the bottom of the page was that Skeet doesn't call background workers, background workers call him - LOL.

Comment: I don't think Jon actually build askjonskeet.com

Comment: Well whoever built it then.