# The rules on impersonation should apply to organisations and products as well

Tags: discussion, terms-of-service

I've recently come across users who've changed their names to "ChatGPT" - and in some cases ran bots that were apparently using ChatGPT as a backend.

The current rules as per meta - see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279108/how-far-should-we-go-in-disallowing-impersonation-in-profiles) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13039/is-it-ok-to-impersonate-a-public-figure) cover public figures as people, and the [rules on companies focus on copyright and trademarks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176079/what-to-do-about-trademarked-usernames).

I don't see any specific guidance as per the current [AUP](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/acceptable-use-policy) or public network [TOS](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public) as of August 2023 nor, even if I squint very hard the [inauthentic usage policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct/inauthentic-usage).

While at least some of the users yielded to a polite request - not everyone might, and I feel that 'the risk of confusion and being mislead' into thinking that an account is genuinely run by or affiliated to an organisation is possible.

As such, I feel that policies around user impersonation should be extended to situations where it is reasonably possible there's confusion due to/over a user's name with regards to companies and products as well.

Since ToSes are revised periodically - for reference, this is the ToS, AUP, and inauthentic usage policy as of August 20, 2023.

[Public Network TOS](https://archive.is/cBbfv) 
[Acceptable Usage Policy](https://archive.is/0nYbx) 
[Inauthentic Usage Policy](https://archive.is/PunJw)

Comment: In a legal context, "person" generally includes other legal entities, such as corporations, partnerships, etc. However, what, exactly, is used depends on the definitions used in the document.

Comment: oh, so you mean that I _**shouldn't**_ be allowed (if I some day wanted to) to name myself `code.visualstudio.com`, `github.com`, or `cmake.org` just to see if it makes me constantly trigger false positives for smokey in my answer posts? fite me!! (joking)

Comment: Essentially yes, that's the idea

Comment: Well, technically, user can choose display name of "Rolls-Royce", put matching avatar, and it would pass as just being funny. ChatGPT is different because of its worldwide vibe and volume, but I'm not sure this can be set into official rules. Should be part of common sense.

Comment: Common sense isn't... always, and hence the "reasonable chance of confusion" - That said, we do have a user on SU whose name and logo is a chinese carmaker...

Comment: Are these users using the name ChatGPT for SEO to get themselves more hits?

Comment: Strangely no, they're just trying to be clever. Spammers are easy, we nuke em and move on. :D

Comment: Was the user actually impersonating ChatGPT or is the rule that users shouldn't use trademarks they don't own as their user name? Yes, ChatGPT is a trademark of OpenAI and that should be reason enough to prohibit people unaffiliated with OpenAI from using it as part of their online presence.

Comment: One actually was vaguely. The other wasn't. IANAL, and it isn't really my job to enforce trademarks. I'm more concerned about the  risk of confusion

Comment: The risk of confusion is the entire reason trademarks exist? You're the one looking for a rule you can point to... I shouldn't be able to change my user name to VSCode or Adobe, obviously.

Comment: Well - the rules I'm pointing to *now* with the name  of public figures does not include trademarks.  I'm very much asking that those rules logically extend to companies rather than creating a new rule

Comment: Why do you need a rule? Is it not obvious that people should not use trademarks they don't own as their name? Anyone who wants to rules-lawyer you about it even though they know they're in the wrong can get escalated to SE. You don't need to go down the rabbit hole of whether they were actually trying to impersonate someone or not.

Comment: @ColleenV: What is obvious to you and me is not obvious to everyone. That's literally the whole point of *having* rules (rather than e.g. just writing "be good" and leaving it there).

Comment: next on the agenda: removing all the users with anime characters names on Anime.SE... I'll wait for your return from the mission in 2070.....