# Cross Stack Exchange Search

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stackexchange.com, global-search

Inspired by this tweet: http://twitter.com/pablogl/statuses/20449580643

As the new, and awesome, StackExchange.com already aggregates the hot questions from across the system. I was wondering if it would be possible to include a global search function also.

Comment: Why is this tagged as "status-completed?"

Comment: @AndersonGreen because they added such a search to stackexchange.com as David says in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://stackexchange.com/search

Answer (score 5):

It's unlikely we would tackle this for a while.

In the meantime a Google search, or [a custom Google search](http://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=014887575466180363695:g0ck1r1qso4), should do the trick.

from:
[How do I Google the whole trilogy of StackOverflow sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5945/how-do-i-google-the-whole-trilogy-of-stackoverflow-sites)

implemented at http://stackexchange.com

[image]

Comment: Note that this obviously also uses Google's search syntax, which [no longer supports the plus-operator](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/websearch/finding-stuff-on-google/3oIWbew9xdE). Instead, quote search terms to force including them, [like `multi user "vpn" "windows"`](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=multi+user+%22vpn%22+%22windows%22). (This does not seem to be a 100% replacement, but the plus-operator certainly doesn't do the trick.)

Comment: Would be nice if a search term would at least lead me to the most appropriate stack. Eg. for a question on 'SCADA' what stack(s) are appropriate? (if any).