# Searching my own questions & answers over all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, search

Today I came across a situation where I knew that I'd answered another similar question some time ago, but couldn't remember on which Stack Exchange site it was. I ended up doing multiple searches on several different Stack Exchange sites before giving up and just doing the research again - answering the question from scratch.

As such, I wonder if it would be possible to implement [the `user: me` syntax](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/943/ability-to-search-my-stuff/10659#10659) on the [Stack Exchange search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66715/add-a-search-box-to-stackexchange-com/66930#66930) mechanism.

If this had already been implemented then it would have given me a single place to try out the different sets of keywords that I thought might help me find my answer.

Note, this question goes one step further than [How can I list all my questions and answers across all Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77206/138432) and I can see that there might be implementation issues with it due to issues raised [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77456/why-doesnt-the-search-textbox-return-searches-from-all-the-different-stack-excha/77458#77458), but couldn't the OpenID for the Stack Exchange account be used to filter the questions and answers from other Stack Exchange sites?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's possible (if you don't mind the results to be a bit stale, they're updated every Sunday morning) with a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/775099/searching-a-users-posts-by-keyword-networkwide). You'll need your network account ID, which you can find in the URL shown in your address bar when you visit https://stackexchange.com/users/current. For example, when I search for my own posts (account ID 6085540) and the word 'company', [these are the results](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/775099/searching-a-users-posts-by-keyword-networkwide?AccountId=6085540&keyword=company#results):

[image]

Of course, Google's search and Stack Exchange own (Elastic)Search are a bit smarter, as they can correct spelling errors, and search for plurals and multiple keywords.

For reference, here is the complete query (feel free to [fork](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/fork/775099) it if you want to play around):

```sql
-- result table, don't rename and keep the site column
create table #results (site nvarchar(250), type nvarchar(10), id int, title nvarchar(250),
  creationdate datetime, score int);

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''   -- holds build up sql string

-- build one biq union sql, for each db
select @sql = @sql 
+ iif( len(@sql) > 1 
     , 'union'
     , 'insert into #results'
) +
-- here goes the per site query, fully qualify the database objects
N'
select ''' + name + '''
     , ''Answer'', a.id, q.title, a.creationdate, a.score
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posts as a
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posts as q on a.parentid = q.id
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.users as u on a.owneruserid = u.id
where u.accountid = ' + CAST(##AccountId:int## AS nvarchar) + '
  and a.body LIKE ''%' + ##keyword:string## + '%'''
  +
'union' +
N'
select ''' + name + '''
     , ''Question'', q.id, q.title, q.creationdate, q.score
from ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.posts as q
inner join ' + quotename(name) + '.dbo.users as u on q.owneruserid = u.id
where u.accountid = ' + CAST(##AccountId:int## AS nvarchar) + '
  and q.posttypeid = 1
  and q.body LIKE ''%' + ##keyword:string## + '%'''
from sys.databases
where database_id > 5

-- AccountId: The global account ID of the user, which you can find in the URL of their network profile. Visit this link: https://stackexchange.com/users/current to see your own ID.

-- execute it
exec (@sql)

-- show results
select
       -- URL builder from Lamak http://stackoverflow.com/a/38129701
      'http://' 
      + case PARSENAME(site,1)
        when 'audio' then 'avp'
        else PARSENAME(site,1)
        end 
      + coalesce('.' 
        + case PARSENAME(site,2)
          when 'audio' then 'avp'
          else PARSENAME(site,2)
          end , '')
      + IIF(patindex('%.MathOverflow%',site) > 0
      , ''
      , coalesce('.' + PARSENAME(site,3), '')
      )
      + IIF(patindex('%.MathOverflow%',site) > 0
      , '.net'
      , '.com'
      ) 
      + (CASE type WHEN 'Answer' THEN '/a/' ELSE '/q/' END)
      + CAST(id AS nvarchar)
      + '|'
      + title,
      type,
      creationdate,
      score
from #results
order by score desc

drop table #results
```

Comment: I see @rene got an apprentice. Nice! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe so. The Stack Exchange network-wide search uses the [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/?hl=en) engine. It's a standard web search based on what Google sees. I do not believe they have that type of access to filter out results based on the post author.

To get around that problem, I typically type in my search followed by my username, which is always embedded in the text (as part of the [flair](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/nowearn-valuable-flair/)).