# Is it possible to search my SE accounts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, search

I asked a question, few months ago, I forgot where I asked it, it could easily fit on SO or Unix.SE or AskUbuntu or SuperUser or Gamedev.SE, and maybe another site. I have accounts on all of these and more.

So is it possible for me to search for my own questions/answers on all SE network without going to every site and checking it out?

Comment: Most of those are under "stackexchange.com" so you can craft a few google searches using *"question terms site:stackexchange.com"* and should be able to find it.

Comment: @AdamDavis yes I know, that's what I'm trying to do know, wouldve been 100 times nicer if it could be done from within SE itself though

Comment: i don't think that a question could fit this amount of sites. For e.g it is not possible to have a question that can be asked on gamedev and unix.

Comment: @Mhmd the question is about android game development engine on linux, so I could have posted it on SO coz there are similar questions there, on gamedev, on unix, on askubuntu coz my OS is  xubuntu, sometimes I ask on unix, on superuser coz I like to be active there, besides, and on android.se coz it has to do with android. you believe me now? I even forgot the title of my question, I'm looking for an sdk that was given to me in the answer...

Comment: @ShadowWizard no, cross site search is impossible to do, coz many questions are the same on different sites, I'm not asking you to be Ethan hunt and do mission impossible, I do realize how hard this is, all I'm asking for is a search for my questions and my answers, it's impossible to ask same question on two sites, even if i do, it will be deleted as cross posting

Comment: @Mhmd is right; a question isn't appropriate for Unix.SE just because you happen to be using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

From any site, click your profile picture in the top bar (or your name on any post by you) to go to your profile on that site. Just above your bio, click Network Profile. This includes a list of all your questions and answers. If you have only a few pages of them, you can scroll through looking for the title you remember.

Failing that, on any given site you can enter `user:me` in the search box along with keywords and find your posts **on that site** with those keywords. ([Searching my own questions & answers over all stack exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102936/147247) asks for `user:me` to work cross-site, but it does not at the moment.)

Which to choose depends on how many possible sites you could have posted on, and how many total posts you have.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I forgot where I asked it, I forgot the title of the question too, it's gonna be hard to find it...