# Make more precise the post searching by author on Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, search-engine

## Scenario

On Stack Exchange it's possible to search for pages around the whole Stack Exchange Network. It was suggested that to search for posts by an author to include their display name. The problem with this solution is that Stack Exchange display names could not be unique, i.e. searching my display name, [Rubén](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=Rub%C3%A9n), returns a lot of users profiles that are not mine, including comments.

[image: Stack Exchange Search results by searching my name]

## Expected behavior

1. Go to http://stackexchange.com
2. Write `author:me`, hit Enter.
3. The results show posts made by the current user.

## Current behavior

### Search results for [author:me]

[image: Stack Exchange results for author:me]

### Search results for [recalc formulas Rubén]

[image: Stack Exchange results for recalc formula Rubén]

## Workaround

- [Query on SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/683547/busqueda-de-publicaciones-de-un-usuario-en-todos-los-sitios?AccountId=1745021&Like=%25recalc%25&OrLike=-1&AndLike2=%25formula%25&AndLike3=-1) (h/t to [Mariano](https://data.stackexchange.com/users/23812/mariano)). This query requires to use the Stack Exchange user id taken from the general SE network user profile.

[image: Enter parameters]

Then it shows the posts made by the user across the SE network. The following snapshot shows the results sorted by "Puntaje" (votes)

[image: Results]

## Related questions

### Meta SE

- [Searching my own questions & answers over all Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102936/289691)

### Stack Overflow en español

- [Buscar todas las preguntas/respuestas que he publicado en la red de Stack Exchange](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2172/65)

Comment: The profile image always has a canonical link to their profile page.

Comment: On Web Apps, my profile image points to my profile on Web Apps, on SO  my profile image points to my  profile on SO and so on.

Comment: That's correct. Did you mean you network profile? Which is linked from your profile page on any of these sites?

Comment: Yes, I mean the SE Network Profile. In my case my it shows a link to my site -> https://stackexchange.com/users/1745021/rub%C3%A9n (replaced Meta SE profile by  SE Network profile)

Comment: So, this is a request to add information to the network profile, similar to what's in per-site profile pages?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to implement the feature that I'm requesting, I just included some ideas about that. Is the expected behavior clear?

Comment: Not really clear - you seem to be asking for several different things here.

Comment: Ups. Thanks a lot for the quick feedback. Maybe I should go back to the "writer desk". I'm not able to fix it right now. Should I deleted it temporally and undeleted it when I have fixed?

Comment: Just leave it here - but be sure to ask for one specific feature (I can't tell if you are asking for improved searching, for better links on the network profile, some combination of both or something different altogether)

Comment: I just edited my question :)