# How can I search my own answers over the whole Stack Exchange network?

Tags: feature-request, search, network-profile, search-engine

I wrote an answer on one of the Stack Exchange sites a while ago, but I don't remember where.

How can I find it by a keyword?

Comment: @Arulkumar It only goes 5 pages back, which is less than 1% of my content. Also I can't find any keyword search there, is there any?

Comment: @gnat that dupe is only applicable to search one site. It doesn't search multiple sites which is what the OP asks for.

Comment: @Whosaysbigcatsdon'twearhats not relevant, it can't filter by user and that's the whole point here. (It's just a custom Google search.)

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably Google, e.g. when I search for

```
site:stackexchange.com glorfindel cliffhangers
```

the [search](https://www.google.nl/search?source=hp&ei=xf9BWs_5GYHIwAKxkq-wDg&q=site%3Astackexchange.com+glorfindel+cliffhangers&oq=site%3Astackexchange.com+glorfindel+cliffhangers&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2428.44519.0.44609.52.44.3.0.0.0.156.3861.28j14.42.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..7.5.563...0j46j0i46k1j0i10k1.0.05MUNByX7yw) returns [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/79902/20215) as a top result. Of course, depending on the occurrence of the keyword and how common your username is, this could lead to a lot of false positives.

Alternatively, you can construct a SEDE query to do this. As @rene is enjoying  Christmas dinner, [I have created one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/305073/295232) now.

Comment: I'm off for Christmas dinner so don't count on it ...

Comment: @rene enjoy! It's doable with SEDE, I'll write an answer on the duplicate target.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently I had deleted that answer. ;( Is it still possible to find? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305107/can-i-still-see-my-own-answers-that-i-deleted