# Can I still see my own answers that I deleted?

Tags: feature-request, support, deleted-answers, search-engine

ADDED. There was the question [What is the 'deleted recent questions' page in the user profile?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185491/what-is-the-deleted-recent-questions-page-in-the-user-profile) referring to the links to **recent questions only** that is apparently only visible to moderators or people with high number of points. This does not help me to find my own questions.

I wrote an answer a while ago that I had subsequently deleted,
after it attracted disappointingly high number of downvotes
that I didn't find rewarding at that time.

Are the deleted answers still kept in the system?

Is there any way to retrieve them?

Comment: If the deleted answer is not more than 60 days old, you can see that under the `Activity -> answers -> deleted recent answers` or by the URL : `https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/<user-id>`. Otherwise you can see that answer if you have 10k reputation on that site.

Comment: I can smell a smell of duplication.

Comment: The "duplicate" question does **not** answer this question. My question is not about **recent**, but all questions. According to answer there, the link is "visible only to profile owners and moderators".

Comment: If it's your post, you're the profile owner...

Comment: @Catija What is your suggestion?

Comment: You said in your edit that you need a lot of reputation... that's not the case. If it's your own post, you need only visit that link. If it's outside the 60 day window, you would have to ask for help from a mod, who can see all posts.

Comment: @Catija Why can't I see my old posts myself?

Comment: You can, or you should be able to. If it's a question, you need a link to it, which a mod can get for you. If it's an answer, you just need to find the question it's on. We don't hard delete much of anything, it's all pretty much still around.

Comment: @Catija But how can I find it by a keyword?

Comment: You can't if it's a question. Only mods can use the site search function to find deleted posts. Again, if it's an answer, you need only find the question.

Comment: [13193](/q/13193) seems like a better dupe candidate. Admittedly, the given dupe this was actually closed as is a little imprecise, but the same basic link is available for answers in the appropriate section.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Shog's answer seems to say that? "*on the Questions and Answers tabs that'll list the given user's deleted questions or answers*"... right?

Comment: @Catija: Sure, but the linked *question* doesn't say it. And the OP here seems to be taking umbrage on the basis that a question about deleted answers should not be duped against one about deleted questions. (I have some sympathy for this, although I'm not sure it matters too much.)

Comment: Agree the first dupe target was wrong. However, this same request was already asked before, and declined.