# See all my questions on all sites where I haven't approved an answer

Tags: support, accepted-answer, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View My questions with Unaccepted Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16869/view-my-questions-with-unaccepted-answers)

Where can I see a list of all questions I've asked with these properties:

- There's at least one answer
- I haven't approved any answers

I'm trying to be better about approving answers, and this would help a lot.

I could write something using SE's API, but I'm guessing this kind of 
page already exists?

Comment: user:me hasaccepted:0 answers:1

Comment: @random To be fair, there's no way to do that across all sites simultaneously, which is what this question seemed to be asking.

Comment: Maybe using SE search instead of Google would be their next improvement of the central spot. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59900/cross-stack-exchange-search @tim

Comment: I know how to see my unanswered questions on a per-site basis, but I'm now on like 30+ stackexchange sites, and wanted to see ALL my unanswered questions in one place. Request re-open, not a duplicate.