# What is the best way to search questions across the entire Stack Exchange network?

Tags: discussion, search, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross Stack Exchange Search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59900/cross-stack-exchange-search)

Is there an effective way to search for questions across Stack Exchange sites, or do I need to repeat the search on Stack Overflow, Super User, and any other SE sites that I think might be relevant?

Comment: this one is for meta

Comment: I often find that Google is more convenient for this than the search box on each site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just search all sites using the stackexchange page? Is that what you mean?

https://stackexchange.com/
[image]

Comment: It's surprisingly hard to find by navigating from another site in the SE network if you don't want to type in the URL. Maybe that's another good idea for a userscript...

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT:

I wrote this before I saw the very simple search on [stackexchange](http://stackexchange.com).

Call this script with `python googse.py "<insert search string>" | less`.  It will search google for anything on stackoverflow.com, serverfault.com or superuser.com.  You get the page title, a summary description and a url.  Unfortunately xgoogle has to be manually downloaded and unzipped in your `PYTHONPATH` (which includes your current working directory).  I hope this is useful.

```
import sys
from xgoogle.search import GoogleSearch, SearchError
# download xgoogle from here
# http://www.catonmat.net/download/xgoogle.zip

def search(topic, sedomain):
    try:
      gs = GoogleSearch("%s site:%s" % (topic, sedomain))
      gs.results_per_page = 50
      results = gs.get_results()
      for res in results:
        print "TITLE: %s" % res.title.encode("utf8")
        print res.desc.encode("utf8")
        print "URL: %s" % res.url.encode("utf8")
        print
    except SearchError, e:
      print "Search failed: %s" % e

for domain in ['stackoverflow.com', 'serverfault.com', 'superuser.com']:
    topic = sys.argv[1]
    print "SEARCHING for '%s'" % topic
    search(topic, domain)
```

Comment: Wow, _what an effort_.

Comment: The Trilogy is *not* the entire StackExchange network! I am offended!

Comment: @RegDwight, LOL... I'm sure you have a text editor ;-)